# Why set value to true using !0

Tags: javascript, boolean, logic

I've recently seen some script in which a property is being set to true using the following.

```
someProp: !0
```

I understand that this will evaluate to true, but don't understand why someone would set a property in this way. Is there a reason?

Comment: It's one less key press ([shift]+!+0 vs t+r+u+e).

Comment: golfing is the only reason I can think of ?

Comment: Some people really, really hate readable code so put things like this in just to screw with their colleagues minds.

Comment: @AwalGarg `1 === true; // false`, if you want false, `!1` ;)

Comment: Is it possible the code went through a minification tool of some sort?

Comment: @MikeCheel Yes, it is. `1` is truthy, but not `true`. `!0` will evaluate to Boolean `false`. Do you agree this is correct?

Comment: @thomas Remember that `!` is a logical **NOT**, `!0 === true`, `!1 === false`

Comment: I think so. http://jsbin.com/liqeb/1/

Comment: I'm surprised it didn't do a !!0 but the shorter version appears to work the same.

Comment: `!!0` would be `false`, so would the shorter `!1`, while `!0` is the shortest way to write `true`, at least if you want a boolean, and not just a truthy value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think there is any specific reason rather a matter of programming and writting code. Some people like things going crazy and I think this is one of them.

!1 means false and !0 - means true